# XSLT - comparing current node with previous sibling

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an input xml looking like this:

```
<vtext>
    <myTag>Title</myTag>
</vtext>
<vtext>
    <myTag> </myTag>
</vtext>
<vtext>
    <myTag> </myTag>
</vtext>
<vtext>
    <myTag>Some text here maybe</myTag>
</vtext>
<vtext>
    <myTag> </myTag>
</vtext>
<vtext>
    <myTag> </myTag>
</vtext>
<vtext>
    <myTag> </myTag>
</vtext>
<vtext>
    <myTag>Other text...</myTag>
</vtext>
```

The `<vtext>` node always contains a single `<myTag>` child node that could be empty. (In this example it is filled in with  , but it can also be something like `<myTag\>`

And what I'm trying to achieve is to have an output HTML that looks like this:

```
Title<br>
<br>
Some text here maybe<br>
<br>
Other text...
```

Basically, I want to replace the multiple empty `<myTag>` nodes after each other with ONLY ONE`<br>` tag. For this I am using a xsl transformation that needs an extra condition that I can not come up with at the moment (can't figure it out)...

What I have by now is this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="myTag">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when
            test="normalize-space(current()) = '' and **SOME CONDITION INVOLVING preceding-sibling MAYBE??**> 
        <br />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
        <br />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Any ideas on what extra condition needs to go there?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `myTag` is a child of `vtext` you probably want to change your `xsl:for-each` to select `vtext` elements rather than `myTag`. Additionally you can then add a condition to select only the ones where `myTag` are non-empty, or where the preceding one is non-empty

```
<xsl:for-each select="vtext[normalize-space(myTag) or normalize-space(preceding-sibling::vtext[1]/myTag)]">
```

So, you are capturing both conditions at once.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"  />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:for-each select="vtext[normalize-space(myTag) or normalize-space(preceding-sibling::vtext[1]/myTag)]">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(myTag)" />
            <br />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done like this:

```
<xsl:template match="vtext">
    <xsl:for-each select="myTag">
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- If the current 'myTag' is empty and the previously one is not append an empty line -->
            <xsl:when 
               test="string-length(normalize-space(current())) = 0 
                         and not(string-length(normalize-space(../preceding-sibling::vtext[1]/myTag)) = 0)">
               <br />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <!-- If the current 'myTag' is not empty, add it to the existing document -->
                    <xsl:when test="not(string-length(normalize-space(current())) = 0)">  
                        <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
                        <br />
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```